# Mouse is too slow in DraftSight

Tags: 15.04

After updating from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 15.04 the mouse on the workspace is too slow. With Ubuntu 14.04 it worked before. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04, but the same problem reoccurred. Needless to say, I reinstalled DraftSight several times on both versions, always the 64-bit. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: English, please!

Comment: Did you try the mouse settings in the system settings application? What kind of mouse do you have? High resolution mice often have means to adjust their sensitivity through a driver or dedicated application.

Comment: @reposted from a comment by fab: The previous version installed DraftSight worked very well!  I was forced to upgrade the program, because "this key/license no longer exists" or something like that.  I tried to force the mouse decrease the DPI, no success. After paying attention to the model screen, you can perceive there are TWO pointers/arrows working together: a square (from DraftSight) and the usual arrow (from Ubuntu). Maybe find a way to "cut" this link, or just leave the usual arrow? Also, the touchpad works perfectly! But it's useless for CAD operations.

Answer (score 5):

Mouse lags in Draftsight 2015 SP2, Ubuntu 14.04, Video Card Nvidia Quadro 600, Nvidia driver version 340.76.

Go to Nvidia X server settings; OpenGL Settings; and uncheck Sync to VBlank. Reboot, this fixed my mouse problem in Draftsight.

SuperMicro X9-SCA series board, Intel E3-1230 Processor, 8 Gig memory.

Comment: it works for me but it's not perfect yet.

Comment: worked for me. no need to reboot.

Comment: I have problem when moving a lot of things together

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for non-Nvidia cards.

I use Ubuntu 15.10 and have Intel GPU integrated. I don't use mouse, just touchpad. However, if you start Draftsight and than plug in a mouse after DS is already runnig, you can use the mouse normaly. Only zoom with wheel doen't work. Moving a pointer with the mouse works than normal and with the touchpad is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I'm also looking to solve this problem.

The previous version installed DrafSight worked very well!  I was forced to upgrade the program, because "this key/license no longer exists" or something like this.

I tried to force mouse decrease the DPI, no sucess.

After paying attention to the model screen, you can perceive there are TWO pointers/arrows working together: a square (from DraftSight) and the usual arrow (from Ubuntu).

Maybe find a way to "cut" this link, or just leave the usual arrow?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 in a notebook  ACER i5 5750-6802, with Logitech M185 wireless mouse.  Also, the touchpad works perfectly! But useless for CAD operations...

Tomorrow I will try a wired mouse...

Comment: Both pointer parts are from DraftSight. When I quickly move my mouse I see the "arrow with square" cursor inside the drawing area and the standard Ubuntu cursor outside. "Display cursor as crosshair" does not solve the problem but fully removes any arrow from the drawing area. Changing the "Pointer size" does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

For **Intel integrated GPU** and Linux Mint 17.2 (which is based on **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**), running from the command line:

`$ vblank_mode=0 /opt/dassault-systemes/DraftSight/Linux/DraftSight`

works fine for **DraftSight 2015 SP3**.

Comment: I have Intel integrated GPU, DS 2015 SP3 and running Ubuntu 15.10 x64 and this solution unfortunately is not solving the issue for me if I open 5MB dwg file.

It works fine if I use new blank file. No lag then.

Comment: @HrvojeT This is indeed true, I have also noticed that this solution works acceptable for small dwg.